# Isn't the gateway statement supposed to work for a subnet?

Tags: networking, gateway

I'm using the following `/etc/network/interfaces` configuration on a Debian machine:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 10.0.0.5/24
gateway 10.0.0.1

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.1.5/24
gateway 192.168.1.16
```

The output of `route` shows that the very last line of the configuration is ignored:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1000   0        0 eth0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
```

Once I run `route add -net 192.168.0.0/24 gw 192.168.1.16`, then the `route` shows the expected gateway:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1000   0        0 eth0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     192.168.1.16    255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 eth1
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
```

Why is `gateway` statement not applied automatically? What am I missing?

Comment: @ilkkachu: the gateway, in my case, is the IP of the router which handles the traffic between the different VLANs on the local network. If I don't specify it, the device attempts to access the other devices directly, which works well when they are on the same VLAN, but doesn't work for the ones which belong to a different VLAN or are hosted by trunked ports. So essentially, I couldn't connect to a bunch of machines until I ran the `route add` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from my understanding you are only able to have one default route which it seems debian will take the first interface configured with a gateway as the default route. in your case eth0, if you are attempting to route to a different subnet within your local network. Your system is on 192.168.1.0/24 network but you would require a static route only to route 192.168.0.0/24 traffic though the local network, if you where to set this as the default gateway this will route all traffic though this gateway which I assume has no other route to the internet.

to add the static route to this second network you could add a new line to your interface file with

```
up route add -net 192.168.0.0/24 gw 192.168.1.16 dev eth1
```

This should make a static route that will persist though a reboot.

Comment: The "_default route_" is the single default route used in the absence of any other routing instruction for off-net addresses. You cannot have two default values for the same item, by definition.